# Can I use a Bash variable in a sed command?

Tags: command-line, bash, sed

I'm trying to execute a `sed` command with "-n" option.

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 ; do maas maas nodes list | grep hostname | cut -d\" -f4 | sed -n '$ip'; done
```

I want it to run  `sed -n '1p'` then `sed -n '2p'` and so on.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You want to replace $i in `$ip` with your shell variable? Use double-quotes

```
... | sed "$ip" ...
```

This has certain implications. It doesn't apply *here* but you might have to escape things you wouldn't need to in single-quote-marks.

But I'd also consider rewriting that so you're not running the same commands *n* times to print the first *n* lines (which is what this does). Here are some alternatives...

Using `head`:

```
maas maas nodes list | grep hostname | cut -d\" -f4 | head -5
```

Storing the command output:

```
output=$(maas maas nodes list | grep hostname | cut -d\" -f4)
for i in 1 2 3 4 5; do
    sed -n "$ip"
done
```

Creating a better `sed` string:

```
maas maas nodes list | grep hostname | cut -d\" -f4 | sed -n $(printf "%dp;" {1..5})
```

Roll all your search/trim code into one `awk`:

```
maas maas nodes list | awk -F'"' '/hostname/ && i<5 {i++; print $4}'
```

I'm an `awk` fetishist so I'd probably go for the last.